# Working principle of an accelerometer

Tags: classical-mechanics, acceleration, inertia

I'm trying to confirm my concepts regarding inertia and accelerometers. Need to verify / correct my thoughts, which are as follows:

Inertia is the property of matter to resist a change in its state of motion. If something is forced to change its state of motion, it has to be done via a physical force that imparts physical acceleration, or **proper acceleration**, to it.

And this is the working principle behind an accelerometer. Since in its simplest form, it's a block of mass attached to a spring (assume only 1D motion for now), if someone with an accelerometer undergoes **proper acceleration**, then so will the accelerometer --> so will the block of mass inside it --> which will stretch / compress the spring.

Is the above correct? Any caveats that I need to be aware of?

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is for. Just trying to clarify my concepts here.

Comment: Not my downvote - it's possible someone dislikes your use of the terms 'inertia' (which is synonymous with mass an pedagogically confusing to keep using) or 'proper acceleration' (which is a specific technical term in relativity which you appear to be using to simply mean 'acceleration').

Comment: @jacob1729: Fair enough, but I wanted to distinguish between coordinate and proper acceleration, and wanted to be more specific.

Comment: @u23 I would suggest expanding your reasoning behind accelerometer in a more detail. It seems to me your chain of those 3 implications is too simplified to see wheter you understand it or not. I would also include what do you mean by "state of motion" since this is crucial in understanding difference between coordinate and physical acceleration.

Comment: @Umaxo: Thanks for the feedback! I probably sound stupid, but I don't know what more details I should include regarding those 3 implications. What I'm trying to get at is the reason an accelerometer can measure proper acceleration. In the context of SR with its flat spacetime (not talking about GR yet), if I'm undergoing proper acceleration and there's an accelerometer comoving with me, then surely the accelerometer is also undergoing proper acc. Since that implies a change of state of motion for the accelerometer, that means it must have a physical force acting on it...

Comment: @Umaxo: ...and by extension, assuming the simplified construction of that accelerometer, the massive block attached to the spring must also have a physical force acting on it, which causes it to compress or extend the spring. Hope my thought process is clearer - I'm not sure how to get more detailed than that

Comment: @u23 "and by extension, assuming the simplified construction of that accelerometer, the massive block attached to the spring must also have a physical force acting on it" I don't understand what you mean by this. How is this extension to be done? Why does it " must also have a physical force acting on it"?

Comment: @Umaxo: If something is undergoing **proper** acceleration, then it's a result of physical forces. I'm not talking about coordinate acceleration. So if I'm experiencing proper acceleration, then anything comoving with me must be experiencing proper acceleration, hence physical force, as well. That's my understanding.

Comment: @u23 Indeed that is true. The next question is why/how does this compress/stretches the string? ...answering these two questions is what I asked for, when I suggested more detail. To explain the implications and not just claim the results. You ask for verification of thoughts, yet it seemed to me you did not really provided them.

Comment: @Umaxo: Ah I see what you meant. As for why it should compress / stretch the spring, since the spring is attached to the block, which experiences a physical force, the spring itself will experience tension because of that - by Hooke's Law, the tension will cause stretching / compression of the spring. Hope that sounds fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be only nitpicking, but I will still post this answer - perhaps it will help a little.

In the light of OP comment:

> since the spring is attached to the block, which experiences a physical force, the spring itself will experience tension because of that

Just because the block experiences physical force it does not mean spring itself will experience tension. When I push on the wall, it experiences physical force, yet the spring will not experience any tension. The tension arises because it is the spring itself that causes this physical force.

That is the whole point of accelerometer. As you said in your question the change in state of motion is always caused by the interaction between bodies (physical force). The accelerometer then claims to be the only source of interaction of mass inside with external world. If this is true, then accelerometer has full knowledge of interactions acting on the mass inside. And from the knowledge of interactions, the proper acceleration can be computed.

In particular, if accelerometer does not exert force on the block of mass inside, you know nothing exerts force on the block of mass inside and the block of mass inside is therefore in an inertial motion, and therefore so is every other comoving object (like accelerometer itself).

In reversed argument (that you are using) you start by assumption that accelerometer is accelerated and that block of mass inside is comoving. Since accelerometer is noninertial, so must be block of mass inside and thus something must interact with this mass inside. Since the accelerometer is only possible source, the cause must lie in the interaction between spring and the block of mass. This last (in my opinion crucial) sentence is missing from your argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying everything! And for filling in the holes in the argument which was the purpose of the question. I have no idea why the question was downvoted - it only serves to demotivate people from asking stuff.